# Related membership gets deleted upon updating owner membership via API

Tags: civimember, api, drupal-8

I would like to make several people a member, linked to 1 payment

- person A: membership (+ contribution)
- person B: membership (related to membership person A)

```
$contact_a = 2;
$contact_b = 3;

$contribution = civicrm_api3('Contribution', 'create', [
  'financial_type_id' => 2,
  'contact_id' => (int) $contact_a,
  'contribution_status_id' => 2,
  'total_amount' => 50,
  'is_pay_later' => 1,
]);

$main_membership = civicrm_api3('Membership', 'create', [
  'contact_id' => (int) $contact_a,
  'membership_type_id' => 1,
  'status_id' => 5,
  'skipStatusCal' => 1,
]);

$part_membership = civicrm_api3('Membership', 'create', [
  'contact_id' => (int) $contact_b,
  'owner_membership_id' => $main_membership['id'],
  'membership_type_id' => 1,
  'status_id' => 5,
  'skipStatusCal' => 1,
]);

$memb_payment = civicrm_api3('MembershipPayment', 'create', [
  'membership_id' => (int) $main_membership['id'],
  'contribution_id' => (int) $contribution['id'],
]);
```

This seems correct, person A gets a membership & contribution, person B gets a membership related to the membership of person A.

As soon as I process the membership payment via the API the contribution is complete and the membership for person A becomes active, BUT the membership for person B is **deleted** !?

```
$complete = civicrm_api3('Contribution', 'completetransaction', [
    'id' => 9, 
    'is_email_receipt' => 0
]);
```

I have simplified the operation to only the membership registrations:

```
$contact_a = 2;
$contact_b = 3;

$main_membership = civicrm_api3('Membership', 'create', [
  'contact_id' => (int) $contact_a,
  'membership_type_id' => 1,
  'status_id' => 5,
  'skipStatusCal' => 1,
]);

$part_membership = civicrm_api3('Membership', 'create', [
  'contact_id' => (int) $contact_b,
  'owner_membership_id' => $main_membership['id'],
  'membership_type_id' => 1,
  'status_id' => 5,
  'skipStatusCal' => 1,
]);
```

And if I then set the membership of person A to "New" the membership of person B is **deleted** !?

```
$new = civicrm_api3('Membership', 'create', [
  'id' => 39,
  'status_id' => "New",
]);
```

The problem therefore lies somewhere with the update of the membership of person A.

Does anyone have an idea?